# Facebook GraphAPI, get user's email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scribe

I want to use GraphAPI to get email. However when I call this in an OAuth request (I'm using scribe, in java), I can retrieve first_name, last_name, but not email, any idea? Tks

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email

Comment: Perhaps [an answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263205/558021) a coupe of days ago will help you here. The email field requires additional permissions from your users.

Comment: The changes will have to be made to your authentication process.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to retrieve `email` from [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object you need to request [`email` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) first.